# Div is getting a double image border - Why?

Tags: html, css, image, border

Okay so, I've got this issue with my `<div>` and when I add my image border, it puts the image there, and doubles it height wise.  And that's my problem.  I only want it to repeat by width.  It's probably something simple, but I'm new with these border-images.

EDIT **

Okay so, I figured out, is there a way to make it so the border-image is only on the top half of the div?  I don't want it on the bottom too.

/EDIT **

JSFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/tzcS3/

Here's my code. 
CSS

```
#section2border {
    border: 30px;
  -moz-border-image:url("images/border-paper-top.png") 30 30 repeat; /* Old firefox */
  -webkit-border-image:url("images/border-paper-top.png") 30 30 repeat; /* Safari */
  -o-border-image:url("images/border-paper-top.png") 30 30 repeat; /* Opera */
  border-image:url("images/border-paper-top.png") 30 30 repeat;
    width:100%;
    background:none;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="section2border">
</div>
```

simple as that, it's just I can't get it to work...  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Its blank for me I don't see any borders anywhere is the JSfiddle correct

Comment: I didn't get this "and doubles it height wise". I have updated the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/raunakkathuria/tzcS3/2/ earlier it was blank

Comment: One border is top and the other one is bottom. Simply add height to the div and you'll see it. (If I understood correctly)

Comment: Check if this is what you require http://jsfiddle.net/raunakkathuria/tzcS3/4/

Comment: Alright I feel dumb, the border is getting added to the top and the bottom of the div, and it's making it look like there's 2 border images.  And I only want one.  Any way to make it so there is only the border-image for the top of the div?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer to your edited question just change

```
#section2border {
    border: 30px solid;
}
```

to

```
#section2border {
    border-top: 30px solid;
}
```

now only top border will be present

http://jsfiddle.net/raunakkathuria/tzcS3/5/

Comment: Thank you, I can't believe I didn't think of that!

Comment: I understand sometimes small things get ignored or dont stuck our mind.. :)

Answer (score 1):

Source: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_border-image-repeat.asp

Your issue is probably because you used repeat, I would suggest "stretch". I was unable to run your JSFiddle but I am assuming that is the issue.

Good luck let us know if it worked.

Try this:

```
#section2border {

    border-top: 30px solid;
  -moz-border-image:url("http://s15.postimg.org/lthkrrwkr/border_paper_top.png") 30 30 repeat; /* Old firefox */
  -webkit-border-image:url("http://s15.postimg.org/lthkrrwkr/border_paper_top.png") 30 30 repeat; /* Safari */
  -o-border-image:url("http://s15.postimg.org/lthkrrwkr/border_paper_top.png") 30 30 repeat; /* Opera */
  border-image:url("http://s15.postimg.org/lthkrrwkr/border_paper_top.png") 30 30 repeat;
    width:100%;
    background:none;
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tzcS3/3/

if you want only top border like you just said just change "border" to "border-top"

Comment: the property is not supported by any browser, specified in same page

Comment: I just checked your JSFiddle and I can see the borders but not in his

Comment: If you add solid to border you will be able to see

Comment: Altho W3Schools (which has **nothing to do with W3C**) has removed most of their nonsense all around their pages, (I still find all the time crazy stuff in there...) they have done more harm than good for all this years to the programming community. So it's payback time. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-image-repeat is a valid link to a really cared documentation. W3S is not. Still.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's because you haven't specified a height and so the top and bottom borders are on top of each other, if you add a height such as 200px they will be seperated and the div's contents will go in-between them.

Hope that helps.